# How to make the css for drawing borders atfer every 3 rows and every 3 columns

Tags: css, sass, vaadin

I am trying to build the css for a table like the sudoko one. any help is really appreciated.
I want to draw border every 3 rows and every 3 columns.

```
  .no-stripes  .v-table-row,.no-stripes  .v-table-row-odd, .v-table-cell-content
    {
    background: white;
    color: $cellcolor;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black; 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `:nth-of-type(3n)` selector for `td` and `tr` elements.

Here [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/yGMLj/1/)

CSS:

```
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

td:nth-of-type(3n) {    
    border-right: 3px solid red;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3n) td {    
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

table {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The `!important` flag is unnecessary here, `td:nth-of-type(3n)` is already specific enough to override styles set on the `td` (same for all the other spots as well).